# Sort K-means label from low to high based on data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a data series of "pressure". I performed a 3 cluster K-means  with scikit. I need the the label that assign the cluster of each data to be sorted from low to high, so 'low pressure' values have the lower label (0), and highest pressure values have the highest label (2). I assigned the labels to a datafrae

This is the code i used:

```
means = KMeans(n_clusters=3,random_state=3425)
dfNS["cB0"] = kmeans.fit_predict(dfNS[["B0"]])
```

Comment: Is this single feature data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard fit. Results in unordered centers.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

means = KMeans(n_clusters=3,random_state=3425)
cB0 = means.fit_predict(np.arange(100).reshape(-1, 1))
print(cB0)
```

output:

```
[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Use

```
ord_idx=np.argsort(means.cluster_centers_.flatten())

cntrs = np.zeros_like(cB0)-1
for i in np.arange(3):
    cntrs[cB0==ord_idx[i]]=i

print(cntrs)
```

output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
```